# how to add new special on foursquare using foursquare api

Tags: ios, foursquare

I am trying to add new special using 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/specials/add but it response bad request always .
and that is the response

Error Domain=com.labratrevenge.HTTPRiot.ErrorDomain Code=403 "forbidden" UserInfo=0x797dc90 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=403 Error: , NSLocalizedDescription=forbidden, headers={type = immutable dict, count = 10,
entries =>
    0 : Case Insensitive Key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin = {contents = "*"}
    2 : Case Insensitive Key: Expires = {contents = "Fri, 19 Oct 2012 10:58:12 GMT"}
    4 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Type = {contents = "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    5 : Case Insensitive Key: Server = {contents = "nginx/1.2.1"}
    6 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Length = {contents = "125"}
    7 : Case Insensitive Key: Connection = {contents = "keep-alive"}
    8 : Case Insensitive Key: Date = {contents = "Fri, 19 Oct 2012 10:58:12 GMT"}
    9 : Case Insensitive Key: Cache-Control = {contents = "no-cache, private, no-store"}
    10 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Encoding = {contents = "gzip"}
    11 : Case Insensitive Key: Pragma = {contents = "no-cache"}
}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting a 403 Forbidden error, which means you are not authorized to add specials. You can only add specials to venues of which you are the manager.